# Unknow cipher with aes-128-cbc

Tags: node.js, cryptography

I'm trying to encrypt a string using `crypto.createCipheriv`.

```js
const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, symetricKey, iv);
let crypted = cipher.update(value, inputEncoding, outputEncoding);
crypted += cipher.final(outputEncoding);
```

The algortihm used is `aes-128-cbc`.

Running this, I get the error `Unknown cipher` and I can't understant what I missed. Can anyone help me about this ? Thank you.

**Edit:**
I let the code [here](https://repl.it/@PanArnaud/ExpensiveLooseBotany).

Comment: I edited my post ! :D

Comment: That should work, unless you've got something invisible in your string, or a damaged build of some kind. Try `crypto.getCiphers()` and if that list doesn't look correct give details about your system and how you got nodejs onto it. PS: nodejs builtin `crypto` is _not_ `cryptojs`

Comment: Sorry, it is morning. Have you checked the requirements for the library? Maybe it is using a native library like OpenSSL?

Comment: `crypto.getCiphers` works correctly. `crypto.createCipher()` too.

Comment: You could test your code online, e.g. [here](https://repl.it/languages/nodejs). If it works there, at least you know for sure that something is wrong with your local environment. Which version do you use and which environment?

Comment: I suspect your `algorithm` variable isn't actually *exactly* `aes-128-cbc`. Distill this to a full example that we can pass to `node` and will show your problem. I suspect when you try to reproduce this in a stand-alone example, you'll discover your error.

Comment: Hi everyone. I tet my code with the online tool [here](https://repl.it/@PanArnaud/ExpensiveLooseBotany). Same error :(

Comment: I can't reproduce the error _Unknown cipher_ in the code posted on _repl.it_. The test key `a-symetric-key` (maybe this is just a dummy) is too short which leads to the error _Invalid key length_. If this is fixed, e.g. `a-symetric-key00`, corresponding to AES-128, the code works. Currently only `cipher` is output, `crypted` would be more useful. Anyway, the code seems to work.

Comment: @Topaco you got it. The correct size for `symetricKey` is 16. The unknowCipher was another error caused by wrong parameters passed by me. My bad. Thank a lot